# Project with androidx.room packed into aar library causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/room/RoomDatabase

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-library, aar

This is the problem that I didn't find any solution on this resource, so please share some knowledge.
I made a lib that works fine as a module.
here's the gradle of it:

```
def room_version = "2.2.6"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
```

now, when I assemle it into AAR, program crashes with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/room/RoomDatabase`

When I googled the problem it turned out that it is a common problem and solution is to switch from `androidx.room` to `android.arch.persistence.room`. But that older version doesn't have `room-rxjava2` I'm using.

So, maybe anyone knows solution of using `androidx.room` in AAR without having a crash?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I found the same issue today

Comment: Even I am stuck on the same issue. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

We must also add the room dependency to the app module (where the aar is imported) to support androidx.room with room-rxJava2 :

```
def room_version = "2.3.0"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// To use Kotlin annotation processing tool
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

// RxJava2 support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this line to app(not the module which assemble to aar)

```
runtimeOnly "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```